# Como criar métodos de extensão em Kotlin

Tags: c#, kotlin

Olá, estou vindo do C# para trabalhar com Kotlin e em C# quando havia qualquer código que era usado constantemente, era comum criar métodos de extensão que funcionassem como atalhos para o mesmo. Ex:

```cs
namespace Test
{
    public static class Test 
    {
        public static string PutDotInEndOfString(this string str) 
        {
            return str + ".";
        }
    }
}
```

Por causa dessa facilidade, estou procurando algo para (ou substituir ou declarar uma nova função) que possa facilitar o uso de métodos simples como o toLowerCase que atualmente me apresenta um warning sobre o default Locale, ex:

```
class Test {
    private lateinit var str: String
    init {
        str = "TEST"
    }
    testMethod(): String {
        // return str.toLowerCase() // assim fica aparecendo o warning
        return str.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
    }
}
```

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer extender ou sobreescrever o método `toLowerCase` no exemplo acima para que não precise ficar passando o locale toda vez que for utilizá-lo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, existe um recurso bem parecido com o de C#. Você só precisa prefixar o nome da função com o tipo que receberá o método de extensão.

Você pode ver mais sobre isso na [documentação](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html).

```
fun String.myToLowerCase(): String {
    return this.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
}

print("KOTLIN IS AWESOME".myToLowerCase())
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando](https://pl.kotl.in/Q6by7939O)**</sup>

Comment: ... cara eu tava pensando que era coisa de outro mundo (afinal kotlin tem java por baixo dos panos)... ta cada vez mais legal mexe com koltin rsrs